# Swift 3 better way to unwrap an optional

Tags: swift, option-type, optional-binding

Right now I have some code that looks like the following:

```
let msg: String? = myStr.removingPercentEncoding ?? nil

print("msg \(msg!)")
```

I really don't like the use of `!` in `msg!` as that can possibly throw an exception, I believe.

What's the best way to call `myStr.removingPercentEncoding` if myStr is not nil and then unwrap msg without throwing an exception?

Comment: Note that `?? nil` is completely redundant in this case.

Comment: By default, `removingPercentEncoding` returns an optional String. It should be: `let msg = myStr.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding`

Comment: @AhmadF `stringByRemovingPercentEncoding` is the old Swift syntax

Comment: @shim Yes, it's Swift 2, and it returns `String?`.

Comment: @AhmadF yes, well read the question. It's written in Swift 3.

Comment: @shim Oh, I see... thanks for the note, but it's still the same :) it returns `String?`. You can check it from [the method documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1642934-removingpercentencoding).

Comment: Yes but it is confusing to comment with syntax that will not compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way would be:

```
if let msg = myStr.removingPercentEncoding {
    print("msg \(msg)")
}
```

Here, `msg` is only valid inside the `if` statement and only if `myStr.removingPercentEncoding` isn't `nil`.

If you wish to print something if `myStr.removingPercentEncoding` is `nil`, then you could and an `else`:

```
if let msg = myStr.removingPercentEncoding {
    print("msg \(msg)")
} else {
    print("msg has no value")
}
```

Read up on [Optional Binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) in the [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH3-ID0) book.

Answer (score 2):

This line is completely useless, when `myStr.removingPercentEncoding` is `nil`, then `nil` (right hand side of `??`) is assigned to `msg`:

```
let msg: String? = myStr.removingPercentEncoding ?? nil
```

Why don't you make it as:

```
let msg: String = myStr.removingPercentEncoding ?? ""

print("msg \(msg)")
```

Comment: Depending on the use case, it may be more desirable to do `let msg = myStr.removingPercentEncoding ?? myStr`, as seeing the full invalid percent-encoded string may be more useful than seeing nothing.

Comment: @Hamish, a possible option, but depends on use case. In some cases, the desired output may be something like `msg --invalid input--`. I think most readers can choose their own alternative value for `""`.